# I am getting error Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, null, sharedpreferences

```
    int _genelScore = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _setScore();
  }

  void _setScore() async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((sharedPreferences) {
      setState(() {
        _genelScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("genelScore")!;
      });
    });
  }
```

I'm designing a simple app where the user is trying to answer a question and score. But " Null check operator used on a null value." I can't get rid of the error. The code above is the page where I show the number of questions that the user knows.

I tried to write int? _generalScore = 0 and make _generalScore nullable. This time, the application works, but if the user misunderstands the first question, high score : null is written on my screen.

```
Text(
        "HIGH SCORE",
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(
        height: 12,
      ),
      Text("$_genelScore",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
              color: Colors.black)),
```

Here is my code where I print the user's record to the screen.

```
    void _updateBestScoreIfNecessary(int correctAnswers) async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((sharedPreferences) {
      var bestScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("genelScore");

      bestScore ??= 0;

      if (bestScore < correctAnswers) {
        sharedPreferences.setInt("genelScore", correctAnswers);
      }
    });
  }
```

Finally, here is my code where I make a key-value match with the word "genelScore" with sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 3):

Initially, At the first time open The `genelScore` key from `SharedPreferences` does not any values saved. So, `sharedPreferences.getInt("genelScore")!;` returns null.

Do,

```dart
_genelScore = sharedPreferences.getInt("genelScore") ?? 0;
```